# The address wasn't understood

Tags: 18.04

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (httpss) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

Comment: what's address exactly Sir?

Answer (score 4):

Please remove the extra `s` from `httpss`. It ought to be `https`.

Comment: httpss is what Firefox said and I did not type, it was a link from another page

Comment: What were trying to do open a web add?

Comment: @JonAsp then complain to the admins of that page that their links are malformed.

Comment: it isnt since it works on chromium

Comment: Put your cursor on that link in firefox and see the url it displays